# How to build Simple 3D app with Silverlight 5 API

Tags: silverlight, 3d, silverlight-5.0

How to make **SIMPLE** 3D application? (just a cube with light and mb with textures) with pure Silverlight 5 API. I don't want to use Babylon, or any other 3D render engine...

PS: I don't nead complicated examples with MultiTextures, BumpMapping ect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to follow the Walkthrough linked below:

> **Creating and Animating a 3D Textured Cube in Silverlight**
>
> > http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg197425(v=XNAGameStudio.35).aspx

---

> **Also Checkout this page which explains the Silverlight 5 beta 3d Support**
>
> > http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg197424(v=XNAGameStudio.35).aspx

I hope that helps you :)

Comment: MSDN.. totally forgot about it :) tnx